# Refreshing window during heavy javascript job

Tags: javascript, html

I have a heavy javascript job that prevents me from showing progress to the user. Is there any way to force refresh the window?

```js
$("button").click(function() 

{
 var date = new Date();
 for (var i = 0; i< 238801000000000000; i++) {
  if (new Date() - date > 5000) {
   document.getElementById('iddds').innerHTML = 'FINISH';
   return;
  }
  if ((i % 10000) == 0) {
   var el = document.getElementById('iddds');
   el.innerHTML = i;
   redraw(el, document.getElementById('parent'));
   
   console.log(i);
  }
 }
});

function redraw(element, e3lement) {
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<div id='parent'>
 <span id='iddds'>Hello world!!!!!!!!!!!!!</span>
</div>

<button>START</button>
</html>
```

I've tried all the answers given here: [How can I force WebKit to redraw/repaint to propagate style changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365/how-can-i-force-webkit-to-redraw-repaint-to-propagate-style-changes?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Force DOM redraw/refresh on Chrome/Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840580/force-dom-redraw-refresh-on-chrome-mac) - and these didn't work, so I assume it is impossible, but given that there are many people who +'d the answers I thought maybe I'm doing something wrong?

- My heavy job is DOM manipulation - Web Workers will not work here.
- I could try to split the job with `setTimeout`'s or something similar, but I do not really want to delay the job or make it slower just to be able to show the progress.

Comment: Consider copying the part of dom you want to manipulate and do that manipulation in web worker  then update dom with new structure

Comment: Two things that should help: 1) Stop scanning the DOM for element references every time you loop. Get them once before the loop begins. 2) Don't use `.innerHTML` when you aren't getting/setting HTML, use `.textContent` instead.

Comment: An occasional `setTimeout( ..., 0 )` should not make the task any slower, other than the time it takes to refresh the DOM.

Comment: Wouldn't `setImmediate()` be more appropriate here?

Comment: Please explain what the `redraw()` function does. What kind of updates are you making to the UI? This may be able to be done with CSS or `requestAnimationFrame()`.

Comment: @AndriyMaletsky What is `setImmediate()`?

Comment: wow, it seems that `setImmediate()` is not standard. My nodejs experience doesn't project well onto frontend, sorry then

Comment: @ScottMarcus This is an artificial example, that I agree I wrote a bit stupidly. Your corrections are proper, unfortunately, do not really help with the problem

Comment: @ScottMarcus `redraw()` is the empty function I wanted to fill with redraw mechanics. I'm coming from C# background so I hoped for something like `Application.DoEvents()` call. I see now there is no such thing

Comment: Did you try working with webworkers or doing the calculation asynchronously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to force refresh the window?

During that single long-running `for` loop on the main UI thread? No, there isn't.

Instead, your choices are:

1. Move that long-running process off the main UI thread into a [web worker](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/); have that worker post updates to the main thread, which it renders in the DOM.
2. Break it up into smaller parts, and after each part use `setTimeout` to schedule the next part, so that the browser has a chance to refresh. The UI will remain blocked during each part, but can update in-between them. Beware that this can make the process take a **lot** longer in real time; a web worker is the way to go if at all possible.

---

(Also best to avoid constantly repeating `getElementById` when you can do it just once at the outset and reuse the reference you get back.)

Comment: I actually had no idea you can do DOM from web worker, this sounds amazing and I definitely will be looking more into web workers, although I still have doubts I can do the thing I'm doing right now. My job is to plot many plots with millions of points with `plotly.js` and then produce a pdf out of it with  `jsPDF`. But thanks, I can for sure count this as an answer - seems like `setTimeout` is the way to go then for now

Comment: @Archeg - Web workers don't have access to the DOM. To update the DOM from the worker, you have to have the worker post a message to the main thread, which does the update. My answer to the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46346297/long-running-code-inside-html-javascript) has a complete example. Happy coding!

Comment: Then it means I can't have Web Workers there as I thought. I have around 1 minute of plotting and generating pdf out of it. But I still need to look more into Web Workers I guess, for now. To be honest I do not really understand the web workers - it looks to me like their usage scenario is extremely limited

Comment: @Archeg - Depending on the details of the plotting and PDF generation, it may be right up their alley -- or not at all, if it's DOM-heavy.

Answer (score -4):

try to add your script in other file and then include it in your file using this below.

```
<script async src="{{url}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: That will reload the document, causing all the JavaScript to stop and the DOM to be reset back to the original state.

Comment: please try the edit one.

Comment: You have completely misunderstood the question, now in two different ways.